# How can I draw straight lines on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to draw some straight lines with the mouse and then delete them by clicking the button. How can I do that on AS3?
Help me please

Comment: normally the easiest way is to use the display object's graphics methods like [lineTo()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineTo()), but in your case, before getting the coordinates for each line you have to figure out the interaction: how do you draw a line (e.g. click and drag start to end point, drag a default line and change it's size and orientation,etc.) and then how you keep track of each line for interaction events(click to delete, etc.). I recommend trying this: 1st learn how to draw a line anywhere...

Comment: ...create an add a display object per line command...then add mouse events to each of the lines in which handlers you remove them, etc...Try figuring out the basic 'ingredients' first and then come back with clearer question on the things you haven't managed to figure out **after** you've tried your best yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a similar question and useful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035665/draw-line-from-object-to-mouse-as3), also, I found a nice [tutorial](http://www.flashandmath.com/basic/mousedraw2/) for you, with example (source code) for a mouse drawing and erase.